# converting startDatetime to localtime using UTC timezone

Tags: java, kotlin, date, datetime-format, java-time

We have a usecase, where we have startDateTime, endDateTime and timeZoneOffset.

timeZoneOffset: UTC-2:30
Here the expected time is mentioned if timezoneOffset is in negative.

| current time | expected time after UTC adjustment |
| --- | --- |
| startDateTime: 2023-07-25T12:40:46.143Z | 2023-07-25T10:10:46.143Z |
| endDateTime: 12023-07-25T12:54:05.558Z | 2023-07-25T10:24:05.558Z |

timeZoneOffset: UTC+2:30
Here the expected time is mentioned if timezoneOffset is in positive.

| current time | expected time after UTC adjustment |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-25T12:43:05.558Z | 2023-07-25T15:10:05.558Z |
| 2023-07-25T12:54:05.558Z | 2023-07-25T15:24:05.558Z |

We are looking for methods in [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), [ZoneOffSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC). But we did not find the methods which we can use to get the expected time.

Can someone please suggest what libraries we can use in Java/Kotlin to get the expected result.

I am expecting the output in DateTime format after adjusting with the UTC value. We wanted to convert the DateTime in local-time.

We have below code snippets for your reference:

```
    var timeZoneOffset: String? = null
    timeZoneOffset: "UTC-08:00"
    

    var startDateTime: LocalDateTime? = null
     startDateTime: 2023-07-25T12:40:46.143Z


    var endDateTime: LocalDateTime? = null
    endDateTime: 2023-07-25T12:43:05.558Z
```

Comment: Could you include some code snippet?
What is your input type and expected output type in java/kotlin?

Comment: If you don't have date, you could rather look at some "time" class, instead of "datetime". And if you want to specify the timezone yourself, that's probably not "local". Have you tried https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-java.time.ZoneOffset- or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence- ?

Comment: You say you 'have' `12:40:46 PM`. What is that? an instance of `LocalTime`? A `String`? A `java.sql.Timestamp`? What? You don't need more libraries, `java.time` can do this, but the question is unclear as to what, exactly, you have.

Comment: Sorry folks. I missed to add code snippet. I have added the type.
@samabcde, I have added the expected and input type in above table.

Comment: Wouldn't you be looking therefore at an end time of 2023-07-25T04:40:46.143?

Comment: The `Z` at the end of your example data means “an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds”. So your prose talking about an offset of -02:30 does not match the data. Your Question does not make sense.

Comment: Another point of confusion: I see [no time zone in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) currently using an offset of 2.5 hours behind UTC.  So why are you trying to use an offset of -02:30?

Comment: Are you working with Newfoundland time? You are correct that it applied an offset of -02:30 in July (because of summer time/DST). If you are, it’s better to use `ZoneId.of("America/St_Johns")`. It’s clearer to read and it automatically takes summer time into account for you.

Comment: You are using `Z` incorrectly and confusingly. UTC times should have a trailing `Z' to tell us they are UTC. This means that local times in some time zone that does not use UTC time should not have the `Z`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are given the offset as a string and sometimes with one digit hours (`UTC+2:30`) and sometimes with two digit hours with leading zero (`UTC-08:00`)?

Comment: Use `Instant` for your current UTC times. If you can get only an offset and not a time zone, convert using `Instant.atOffset()` [My full solution is on Kotlin Playground here](https://pl.kotl.in/vc9iTWYB5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is for time zone only, refer to [Basil's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916295/7928721) for offset

Not quite sure why you represent 2023-07-25T12:54:05.558Z in `LocalDateTime`, as Z indicate UTC+0, so it should be `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Base on the given example, what you are trying is like

1. Given a input at UTC+0, find the equivalent time at given zone offset
2. Change the zone back to UTC+0 without changing the time

And it could be done using:

- [`withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant(java.time.ZoneId)) for (1)
- [`withZoneSameLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameLocal(java.time.ZoneId)) for (2)

Below demonstrate how to implement such adjustment in kotlin.

```kotlin
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

fun main() {
    val timeZoneOffset = "UTC-02:30"

    val zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of(timeZoneOffset.replace("UTC", ""))

    val startDateTime: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-07-25T12:40:46.143Z")
    println(adjustZone(startDateTime, zoneOffset))

    val endDateTime: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-07-25T12:43:05.558Z")
    println(adjustZone(endDateTime, zoneOffset))
}

fun adjustZone(zonedDateTime: ZonedDateTime, zoneOffset: ZoneOffset)
        : ZonedDateTime {
    return zonedDateTime
        .withZoneSameInstant(zoneOffset)
        .withZoneSameLocal(zonedDateTime.zone)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Samabcde for your kind help. This will going to work to support my usecase.

Comment: Wrong class here. `ZonedDateTime` is for time zones, not offsets. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916295/642706) for correct use of `OffsetDateTime` class.

Comment: @BasilBourque Or `Instant` for the UTC time, assuming it’s for holding the point on the timeline without regard to time zone or offset.

Answer (score 2):

## `OffsetDateTime`

Your Question is thoroughly confusing. But if you are simply trying to view a moment through the lens of a particular offset, use `ZoneOffset` and `OffsetDateTime`.

Understand that the `Z` on the end of your strings indicates an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime odtZero = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2024-01-23T18:00:00Z" ) ;
```

Specify your desired offset.

```
ZoneOffset offset2H30M_BehindUtc = ZoneOffset.parse( "-02:30" ) ;
```

[Apply the offset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset)).

```
OffsetDateTime odt2H30M_BehindUtc = odtZero.withOffsetSameInstant( offset2H30M_BehindUtc ) ;
```

Same moment, same point on the timeline, different well-clock-time.

Note that no time zone currently uses an offset of 2 hours and 30 minutes behind UTC. So I find your particular offset to be suspicious.

Be aware that time zones should generally be used in preference to offsets. Calculating elapsed time, or projecting into the past or future, may result in unexpected/incorrect values when using offsets alone.